# "Evaluating" polynomials of functions (Symbols)

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I want to implement the following type evaluation symbolically

$$(f^2g + fg + g)(x) \to f(x)^2 g(x) + f(x) g(x) + g(x)$$

In general, on left hand side there is a polynomial in an arbitrary number of functions (e.g. $f, g^3 h, (f_1 + f_2 + f_3)^3, \dots$ and on the right hand side all the functions have been evaluated at the same element $x$. I would to define a function `eval` or a rule such that

```
In[1]:= (f^2g + fg + g)[x] // eval
In[2]:= f[x]^2 g[x]+ f[x] g[x] + g[x]
```

What is a good way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
polyThrough[h_[a___]] := h /. Map[#1 -> #1[a] &, Variables[h]]
((3 f^2 g + 5 f g + g)^2 )[x, y, z] // polyThrough
```

[image]

```
((a - b)/(x + y) - 2/z)[] // polyThrough
```

[image]

Comment: That's concise! For arbitrary coefficients one can filter `Variables[h]` with `/. v_?coeffQ -> Sequence[]` given the Boolean function `coeffQ`.

Answer (score 9):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use `Through`, as in

```
Through[(f + g)[x]]
```

> `f[x] + g[x]`

However, this is a little tricky to apply when you also have powers as in `f^2` - so in your case it seems to be more efficient to make use of the fact that all symbols are evaluated at the *same* `x` anyway (i.e., there isn't any `f[y]` and `f[z]` anywhere). Then you could simply do this:

```
eval = s_?(MemberQ[{f, g}, #] &) :> s[x]

(* ==> s_?(MemberQ[{f, g}, #1] &) :> s[x] *)

f^2 g + f g + g /. eval

(* ==> g[x] + f[x] g[x] + f[x]^2 g[x] *)
```

**Edit**

The above replacement rule `eval` restricts the names of your functions to `f` and `g`, but the list could be expanded arbitrarily. Having an explicit "white list" of names for allowed functions is safer in my opinion. However, one can also construct patterns that don't rely on a knowledge of the function names, as long as we can make some other assumptions.

In response to the comment, let's assume that your polynomial has the added special property that it contains no symbolic constants as coefficients. Then we can be sure that all symbols that aren't arithmetic operations must be functions of `x`, and therefore, we could test for the property `NumericFunction` among the `Attributes` of a symbol:

```
eval = 
 s_Symbol?(! MemberQ[Attributes[#], NumericFunction] &) :> s[x]

(*
==> s_Symbol?(! MemberQ[Attributes[#1], NumericFunction] &) :> 
 s[x]
*)

f^2 g + f g + g /. eval

(* ==> g[x] + f[x] g[x] + f[x]^2 g[x] *)
```

This allows you to use any symbol for your functions, as long as it's not a reserved name for a numeric function such as `Plus`, `Times` or `Power`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Your solution works fine when a small number of symbols is involved. In my case I do not know beforehand the "function" names.

Comment: Well, in general when specifying a polynomial one does have to state what are the variables and what are the coefficients. The list `{f, g}` serves that purpose of identifying what space your polynomial lives in. So are you saying that all the possible coefficients in your polynomial are going to be numerical values?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You are correct in that I need to specify a pattern for either the polynomial variables or the coefficients.

Comment: Is there any advantage of your pattern `s_?(MemberQ[{f, g}, #] &)` over the simpler `s:(f|g)`?

Comment: @celtschk No, except that you could define `vars = {f, g}` as a list beforehand as a global variable and then use it here as `vars`.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work pretty well, and not only for polynomials.

Not sure about its robustness.

```
eval[r_] := r /. u_[s__] :> u /. x_Symbol /; Context@x == "Global`" :> x @@ Level[r, {-1}]
```

Test drive

```
(3 f^2 g + f g + g)[u, w] // eval
(*
-> g[u, w] + f[u, w] g[u, w] + 3 f[u, w]^2 g[u, w]
*)


(f^g + d)[w, v] // eval
(*
-> d[w, v] + f[w, v]^g[w, v]
*)


(Sin[h] f + 3 d)[u] // eval
(*
-> 3 d[u] + f[u] Sin[h[u]]
*)
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to introduce coefficients other than numeric symbols?

Comment: @RYogi Define them in any Context other than Global :)

Comment: @RYogi If you decide to try this answer, please comment about its robustness, as I'm afraid I did a very limited testing

Comment: `Context` ... of course ;)

Comment: It doesn't behave on expression like the last example in my answer. In a sense it's too flexible to play nice with polynomials.

Comment: @RYogi Yep. You're right. And I think that is not easy to fix with this method. It was fun anyway :). Good question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is slight modification that generalizes Jens's.

```
eval[sympoly_, coeffQ_:False] := Head@sympoly /. s_?
    (MemberQ[
       Variables[Head@sympoly] /. v_?coeffQ -> Sequence[]
       , #] &
     ) :> s[Level[sympoly, 1] /. List -> Sequence]
```

The pattern `sympoly_` holds an expression of the form `(f^2g + fg + g)[x]`, as in the question. Jen's evaluation rule is applied to the `Head` of `sympoly`, while the evaluation point is extracted using `Level` and the r.h.s. of Jen's rule `s[x]` modifed to `s[Level[sympoly, 1] /. List -> Sequence]`.

Which expressions in `sympoly` are to be considered variables is checked with a Boolean test (`MemberQ`). First, all possible variables are obtained using `Variables`. Then, they are filtered with a rule to exclude coefficients (using the ad-hoc test function `coeffQ`). By default numerical symbols are coefficients as they are not recognized as variables by `Variables`. The variables of sympoly are the output of

```
Variables[Head@sympoly] /. v_?coeffQ -> Sequence[]
```

Here's an example

```
(3 f^2 g + f g + g)[x] // eval
```

> ```
> g[x] + f[x] g[x] + 3 f[x]^2 g[x]
> ```

Here coefficients are `h[i], h[j], h[k]` (any symbol with head `h`):

```
eval[(h[i] f^2 g + h[j] f g + h[k] g)[x], Head[#] == h &]
```

> ```
> f[x]^2 g[x] h[i] + f[x] g[x] h[j] + g[x] h[k]
> ```

The function `eval` works also on more general symbols

```
(3 f[1]^2 f[2] + ff g[f[h]])[x, y, z] // eval
```

> ```
> 3 f[1][x, y, z]^2 f[2][x, y, z] + ff[x, y, z] g[f[h]][x, y, z]
> ```